# How to programatically inject html to qunit-fixture

Tags: javascript, requirejs, qunit

I would like to programatically inject the html to test into the qunit-fixture. I have tried with $.load but the JS dealing with the HTML gets executed before the html is loaded.

The HTML:

```
<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>

<script src="../components/bower/qunit/qunit/qunit.js"></script>
<script>
  QUnit.config.autostart = false;
</script>

<script data-main="tests" src="../components/bower/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

The JS manipulating the html is the module I want to test:

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {

  'use strict';

  var Foo = {
    _init: function() {
      this._addClass();
    },
    _addClass: function() {
      console.log('adding class testit');
      $('.foo').addClass('testit');
    },
    greet: function() {
      return "Hello";
    }
  };

  Foo._init();

  return {
    greet : Foo.greet
  };

});
```

And my test:

```
define(['foo'], function(foo) {

  'use strict';

  var Test = {
    test: function() {
      module( "module Foo");
      asyncTest("foo class test", function() {
        expect(1);
        // foo() is executed before load is done :(
        $('#qunit-fixture').load('../components/app/foo/foo.html', function(data) {
          ok($('.foo').hasClass('testit'), ".foo should have class 'testit'");
          QUnit.start();
        });
      });
    }
  };

  return {
    test: Test.test
  };

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the loading of the content is asynchronous you'll need to [tell QUnit to wait before running](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.config/). Note that this is just a guess at what your test harness **might** look like, it will likely need to be updated for your use case.

```
<!-- in your test HTML document -->
<script>
QUnit.config.autostart = false;

// your code to load the HTML dynamically in the fixture

// your test definitions

require(
    [ "src/yourSourceCode", "tests/theTests" ],
    function() {
        QUnit.start(); // this starts the main QUnit code
    }
);

</script>
```

**UPDATE**

Looks like the OP is, in fact, already stopping QUnit from running immediately, the problem (see the comment below) is that the module code runs before the HTML is loaded dynamically. I think this is because the `_init()` method is called inside the module. Instead, return the `_init` method as a property of the module and call it from the test:

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {

  'use strict';

  var Foo = {
    _init: function() {
      ...
    },
    ...
  };

  // Foo._init(); // don't do this here...

  return {
    greet : Foo.greet,
    init : Foo._init    // add the init method to your exports
  };

});
```

Now, in your test you can do:

```
define(['foo'], function(foo) {

  'use strict';

  var Test = {
    test: function() {
      module( "module Foo");
      asyncTest("foo class test", function() {
        expect(1);

        $('#qunit-fixture').load('../components/app/foo/foo.html', function(data) {

          foo.init(); // we've moved the initialization to here...

          ok($('.foo').hasClass('testit'), ".foo should have class 'testit'");
          QUnit.start();
        });
      });
    }
  };

  return {
    test: Test.test
  };

});
```

Comment: I added the HTML to the original question. There you can see that I already stopped qunit from autostarting. The Problem is not that the test runs bevore require loads the modules. But the loaded module starts before the test inserts the HTML into the the qunit-fixture

Comment: Aaah... I see. Well the problem there is that you call the `Foo._init();` method immediately in the module. I'll update this answer to demonstrate how you can get around this issue.

Comment: That of course eliminates the problem. But I don't want to change the logic of my app to make the tests work. Or maybe this is the essence of the test first paradigm? It just doesn't feel right to me to make private functions public for the sole purpose of testing it.

Comment: Hmm... I guess this is a methodology question then. I would argue that the module paradigm does not require that modules initiate themselves. In fact, in most cases I *always* export some kind of "kick off" method for my modules. Maybe this module won't be used in any other context, but consider if it were... would that other context be pre-setup? What if it were an SPA with dynamic content? In any case, if you want to dynamically load content then you have to delay execution of your module code somehow.

Comment: thanks for sharing a different view on the matter, it always helps to hear other opinions :)